# Override from GraphQL Schema generated Typescript types

Tags: typescript, code-generation, typescript-generics

Im using the [graphql-code-generator](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator) to generate typescript types out of my GraphQL schema.
In GraphQL you can create custom scalar types which will generate the following type:
`/graphql.ts`

```
export type Scalars = {
  String: string;
  Boolean: boolean;
  NodeDescription: any;
};

export type CodeResource = {
  ast: Scalars["NodeDescription"];
};
```

As you can see the GraphQL default scalar types like String, Boolean etc. will be mapped on the equivalent Typescript type. Custom scalar types like `NodeDescription` will get the typescript type `any`.

In my Angular Client there already is a `NodeDescription` type (in ../app/shared/syntaxtree) which I want to use instead of the generated `any` type.
Is there a way to override the `NodeDescription` field in Scalars type?
So in the end I want the `ast` field of the generated CodeResource type to have the type `NodeDescription` instead of `any`.

My first idea was to override the the `Scalars["NodeDescription"]` type with `NodeDescription`. So I tried to import all types in a new file and override them like:
`/types.ts`

```
import {Scalars} from "./graphql";
import {NodeDescription} from "../app/shared/syntaxtree";
type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U;
type Scalar = Overwrite<Scalars, {NodeDescription: NodeDescription}>
```

This actually works, but the `ast` field of the `CodeResource` type still is type `any`.

Another idea is to use a bash script with a well thought out `sed` command so the generated file will be edited like:

```
import {NodeDescription} from "../app/shared/syntaxtree";
export type Scalars = {
  String: string;
  Boolean: boolean;
  NodeDescription: NodeDescription;
};
```

However before I implement that approach I would like to know if there is a smart typescript way to override the generated types. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a specific solution if you have the same problem using [graphql-code-generator](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator). There is a plugin called [add](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/add).
So in the codegen.yml you are able to add imports and address the custom scalar types. My codegen.yml now looks like that:

```
overwrite: true
schema: "../schema/graphql/schema.json"
documents: "../schema/graphql/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-apollo-angular"
      - add:
          content: 'import { NodeDescription } from "../app/shared/syntaxtree";'
    config:
      enumsAsTypes: true
      scalars:
        NodeDescription: NodeDescription
        ISO8601DateTime: string
```